# How can I reset the table pagination to the beginning whenever the search keyword changes or the page limit is modified?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I'm working with a React and Ant Design (antd) generic table and have created a `useTableData` hook to supply data to various tables in my application. Currently, the table is functional, but it has some flaws that are noticeable to the end user. Here are a few of them:

- The table does not reset to page 1 when the search keyword is changed.
- Changing the page limit does not reset the table to page 1.
- Altering the page limit also disrupts the serial numbers.

Here is the hook

```js
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
/* eslint-disable no-sparse-arrays */
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export const useTableData = ({
  fetchFunc,
  defaultColumn,
  sorterDefault,
  tableParams,
  setTableParams,
}) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const getSorterValue = (key, order) => {
    return key
      ? `${
          key === 'name'
            ? 'firstName'
            : key?.replace(/[A-Z]/g, (letter) => `_${letter?.toLowerCase()}`)
        }:${order === 'ascend' ? 1 : -1}`
      : sorterDefault;
  };

  const handleTableData = (tableConfig = null) => {
    let page = (tableConfig ?? tableParams).pagination?.current;
    let limit = (tableConfig ?? tableParams).pagination?.pageSize;
    let attributes = `${defaultColumn
      .map((el) => el.attributeName)
      .filter((el) => el)
      .join()},id`;
    let sort = getSorterValue(
      (tableConfig ?? tableParams).field,
      (tableConfig ?? tableParams).order
    );

    console.log(attributes);
    dispatch(
      fetchFunc({
        limit,
        page,
        sort,
        search: text,
        attributes,
        is_active:true
      })
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (text.length > 3) {
      handleTableData();
    }
    handleTableData();
  }, [, text]);

  const handleTableChange = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
    setTableParams({
      pagination,
      filters,
      ...sorter,
    });

    handleTableData({
      pagination,
      filters,
      ...sorter,
    });
  };

  const handleLimitChange = (value) => {
    handleTableData({
      ...tableParams,
      pagination: { ...tableParams.pagination, pageSize: value },
    });
    setTableParams({
      ...tableParams,
      pagination: { ...tableParams.pagination, pageSize: value },
    });
  };

  return {
    tableParams,
    setTableParams,
    text,
    setText,
    handleTableData,
    handleTableChange,
    handleLimitChange,
  };
};
```

So to give more clarity on the props here is the `tableParams` state

```
const [tableParams, setTableParams] = useState({
  pagination: {
    current: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
    total: count && count,
  },
});

const { setText, handleTableChange, handleLimitChange } = useTableData({
  fetchFunc: getModule, // Api call with redux which provides the count and data
  defaultColumn,
  sorterDefault,
  tableParams,
  setTableParams,
});

<Table
  tableColumns={columnDef}
  data={module}
  handleSorting={handleTableChange}
  onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
  count={tableParams?.pagination?.total ?? 0}
  limit={tableParams.pagination.pageSize}
  currentPage={tableParams.pagination.current}
  setLimit={handleLimitChange}
/>
```

I believe the issue stems from using a single `useEffect`, which may be causing these problems. Another issue could be the lack of page resetting.

I tried reseting the page and use different function for different calls but i am getting stack because of the way my `useEffect` is working.

Comment: What's the version of antd?

Comment: "antd": "^4.23.1", @LinDu

Comment: Can you make a running demo using https://codesandbox.io to reproduce your issue?